# How do I close all the goroutines that are "asleep"?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have a goroutine running in a for loop:

```
    func main(){
           for _, i := range x{
               go httpRequests(i, ch)
           }

           for i := range ch{
              print i

        }
    }

func httpRequests(i, ch){
           for _, x := range y{
               go func(string x){
                  do something with i
                  ch <- result
              }(x)
           }


           }
```

When I run that, it says all goroutines are asleep. Any suggestions?

Comment: You must show actual code.

Comment: I think my sample code in the link above is enough to get me started. If you run that code, you can see its printing the same output. What I want is iterate through the ids and print all of them

Comment: I don't have the time to debug this code but I suggest you read this whole document:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started 3 goroutines (`go serviceReq(i, httpCh)`) passing them a channel. And then you receive on that channel only **once** (`ch := (<-httpCh).serviceData`).

Instead of that you should receive in a loop:

```
for resp := range httpCh {
    output = append(output, resp.serviceData)
}
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense however, now I'm stuck on "all goroutines are asleep- deadlock". I've been trying to add waitgroups and close the channel but not getting far. Any suggestions?